# Union find using unordered map and templates in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, template, c++17, union-find

I tried to implement union find (disjoint set data structure) algorithm in C++. There I used unordered_map data structure. Is there a better way of doing this using any other data structure.

While finding the root I have used the following way.

```
int root(int i){
        if(i != parent[i]) parent[i] = root(parent[i]);
        return parent[i];
    }
```

Also, I can implement it as

```
int root(int i){
        while (i != parent[i]){
            parent[i] = parent[parent[i]]);
            i = parent[i];
        }
        return i;
    }
```

It seems like both are same other than the (recursive and iterative) approach for me. Which is better here!

The following is my implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

class Disjoinset{

    private:

    unordered_map<int, int> parent, rank;
    // find the root
    int root(int i){
        if(i != parent[i]) parent[i] = root(parent[i]);
        return parent[i];
    }

    public:

    // initialize the parent map
    void makeSet(int i){
        parent[i] = i;
    }
    // check for the connectivity
    bool is_connected(int p, int q){
        return root(p) == root(q);
    }
    // make union of two sets
    void Union(int p, int q){

        int proot = root(p);
        int qroot = root(q);

        if(proot == qroot) return;

        if(rank[proot] > rank[qroot]) {
            parent[qroot] = proot;
        }
        else{
            parent[proot] = qroot;
            if(rank[proot] == rank[qroot]) rank[qroot]++;
        }
    }
};
```

Driver code

```
int main(){
    vector<int> arr = {1,2,9,8,6,5,7};
    Disjoinset dis; // create a disjoint set object
    for(int x: arr){
        dis.makeSet(x); // make the set
    }
    dis.Union(1,9); // create connections
    dis.Union(6,5);
    dis.Union(7,9);
    cout <<  dis.is_connected(1,7) << endl; // check the connectivity.
    cout <<  dis.is_connected(1,6) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thereafter I tried to use generics and I came up with following. Can someone help me on this as I am new to C++. Is my implementation is correct or are there any better approach.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Disjoinset{

    private:

    unordered_map< T, T> parent; 
    unordered_map< T, int>rank;
    // find the root
    T root(T i){
        if(i != parent[i]) parent[i] = root(parent[i]);
        return parent[i];
    }

    public:

    // initialize the parent map
    void makeSet(T i){
        parent[i] = i;
    }
    // check for the connectivity
    bool is_connected(T p, T q){
        return root(p) == root(q);
    }
    // make union of two sets
    void Union(T p, T q){

        T proot = root(p);
        T qroot = root(q);

        if(proot == qroot) return;

        if(rank[proot] > rank[qroot]) {
            parent[qroot] = proot;
        }
        else{
            parent[proot] = qroot;
            if(rank[proot] == rank[qroot]) rank[qroot]++;
        }
    }
};


int main(){
    vector<string> arr = {"amal", "nimal", "kamal", "bimal", "saman"};
    Disjoinset <string>dis; // create a disjoint set object
    for(string x: arr){
        dis.makeSet(x); // make the set
    }
    dis.Union("amal", "kamal"); // create connections
    dis.Union("kamal", "nimal");
    cout <<  dis.is_connected("amal", "nimal") << endl; // check the connectivity.
    cout <<  dis.is_connected("bimal", "amal") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you for every answer.

Comment: Did you test it? Does it produce the correct output?

Comment: @Mast Did you find anything wrong here?

Comment: Without a specification what, e.g. `int root(int i)` is to accomplish, who is to tell if it works as intended, is coded justifiably? (I see the single line comments in the larger code blocks. I'm, old, trying to be patient. And attentive. Failing time and again…)

Comment: @greybeard sorry for that. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall, that looks good to me. A few nitpicks, however, follow:

**Advice 1**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
```

I would put a space between `e` and `<`. Also, I would sort the rows alphabetically, so that we get:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
```

**Advice 2: One template per file**

I would extract away the `main` and put the entire disjoint set template into its own file; call it `DisjointSet.hpp` to begin with.

**Advice 3: Protect your header files from multiple inclusion**

I would most definitely put the header guards in `DisjointSet.hpp` so that it looks like this:

```
#ifndef COM_STACKEXCHANGE_RUSIRU_UTIL_HPP
#define COM_STACKEXCHANGE_RUSIRU_UTIL_HPP
.
. Your funky DisjointSet.hpp code here. :-)
.
#endif // COM_STACKEXCHANGE_RUSIRU_UTIL_HPP
```

**Advice 4: "Package" your code into namespaces**

I have a habit of putting my data structures into relevant namespaces in order to avoid name collisions with other people's code:

```
namespace com::stackexchange::rusiru::util {
    template<class T>
    class DisjointSet {
        ...
    };
}
```

**Advice 5: Remove minor noise**

```
unordered_map< T, T> parent; 
unordered_map< T, int>rank;
```

I would write:

```
unordered_map<T, T> parent;
unordered_map<T, int> rank;
```

Note the placement of spaces!

**Advice 6: Arbitrary method naming scheme**

Essentially, you have `makeSet`, `is_connected`, `Union`. That's three different method naming schemes right there; choose one and stick to it. For example, `makeSet`, `isConnected`, `union`.

**Advice 7: Printing booleans to `stdout`**:

You can do `cout << std::boolalpha << ...;` in order to print `true`/`false`.

**Advice 8: Don't pollute your namespace**

Generally speaking, `using namespace std;` is not what you may see in professional C++ code. Consider using individual `use`s such as:

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

**Putting all together**

Overall, I had this in mind:

**`DisjointSet.hpp`**

```
#ifndef COM_STACKEXCHANGE_RUSIRU_UTIL_HPP
#define COM_STACKEXCHANGE_RUSIRU_UTIL_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

namespace com::stackexchange::rusiru::util {

    using std::boolalpha;
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;
    using std::string;
    using std::unordered_map;
    using std::vector;

    template<typename T>
    class DisjointSet {

    private:

        unordered_map<T, T> parent;
        unordered_map<T, int> rank;

        // find the root
        T root(T i) {
            if (i != parent[i]) parent[i] = root(parent[i]);
            return parent[i];
        }

    public:

        // initialize the parent map
        void makeSet(T i) {
            parent[i] = i;
        }
        // check for the connectivity
        bool isConnected(T p, T q) {
            return root(p) == root(q);
        }
        // make union of two sets
        void union(T p, T q) {

            T proot = root(p);
            T qroot = root(q);

            if (proot == qroot) return;

            if (rank[proot] > rank[qroot]) {
                parent[qroot] = proot;
            }
            else {
                parent[proot] = qroot;
                if (rank[proot] == rank[qroot]) rank[qroot]++;
            }
        }
    };
}

#endif // COM_STACKEXCHANGE_RUSIRU_UTIL_HPP
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
#include "DisjointSet.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::boolalpha;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::vector;
using com::stackexchange::rusiru::util::DisjointSet;

int main() {
    vector<string> arr = { "amal", "nimal", "kamal", "bimal", "saman" };
    DisjointSet<string> dis; // create a disjoint set object

    for (const string x : arr) {
        dis.makeSet(x); // make the set
    }

    dis.union("amal", "kamal"); // create connections
    dis.union("kamal", "nimal");

    cout << boolalpha << dis.isConnected("amal", "nimal") << endl; // check the connectivity.
    cout << dis.isConnected("bimal", "amal") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed advises. Those are really helpful.

Comment: Nothing about `using namespace std;`?

Comment: @pacmaninbw Mitigated.

Comment: I wouldnt recommend sorting the inclusions alphabetically, since you sometimes need to worry which one goes first. You also sometimes want to separate standard ones from custom ones.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for unordered maps, especially not for two of them. Also, since you are dealing with indices and counts, you should make them `std::size_t`, not `int` or generic. The datatype for storing parent-rank-tuples should look like this:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<std::size_t, std::size_t>> data;
```

Performance will be a good deal better because `vector` is faster than `unordered map` and in addition to that, there's only one lookup required to get both parent and rank, like this:

```
auto [parent, rank] = data[i];
```

or like this:

```
std::tie(parent, rank) = data[i];
```

If you want the union-find datastucture to work on arbitrary objects instead of indices, create a generic wrapper class that translates objects to indices and then invokes the non-generic version. This way, the `unordered_map` lookup is done only once for each argument, even if the non-generic version subsequently performs several recursions.

Comment: P Thanks. What did you mean by " vector is faster than unordered map". Better if you can you explain it .

Comment: @rusiruthushara - `std::vector` is an array and `std::unordered_map` is a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). A hash table is built upon an array but with key hashing and collision handling on top, so it is obviously slower than a plain array. The disadvantage of an array is that the keys must be integers between zero and the size of the array. A hash table can handle arbitrary indices, including strings and objects.

Comment: Thanks for the information.